# image button for deleting users from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

so I've got a problem

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['fio']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['born_date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['number']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['work_post']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['inwork_date']; ?></td>

            <td><center><form action="delete.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$row['user_id'].'"><input type="Submit" class="deleteButton" value="Delete"></form></center></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
```

and in delete.php I have

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

        $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";

        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        header("Location: edit.php");

        exit;
    }

?>
```

I see list of users - it works! But I can not delete anybody.

Comment: Put in `delete.php` this  `var_dump($_POST);` to see what is really sent to server.

Comment: array
  'user_id' => string ''.$row['user_id'].'' (length=19)
  'Submit' => string 'Delete' (length=6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not correctly inserting the ID due to the fact that the PHP interpreter isn't "active" where you seem to think it is.

As such, change...

`<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$row['user_id'].'">`

...to...

`<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>">`

...and all will be well. (It happens to us all occasionally.)

Incidentally, wrapping each delete link in a form is perhaps a bit excessive - is there a reason you don't want to use a "normal" link?

**UPDATE**

You'll also most likely need to explicitly use the HTTP post variable on your delete page as follows:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id='" . intval($_POST['user_id']) . "'";
```

Comment: yeah, you're right - now it post good, but... maybe i'm wrong in delete.php - blank screen - query and header don't work

Comment: there's 1 reason - it's only for design

Comment: @user711227 Check your error logs if you're getting a blank screen.

Comment: ok thanks, I forget include ('../mysql.php'); where I connect to mysql, now header work, but delete from mysql still doesn't work... sorry for my english

Comment: @user711227 I've updated my answer with a tweak that should hopefully help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="Submit" class="deleteButton" value="Delete">
```

You need a name on this field to pass your if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

```
<input type="Submit" class="deleteButton" value="Delete" name="Submit">
```

On a slightly different note, I hope you are doing some sort of check that the user executing the delete call has permissions.